# design a logic circuit odd/even driver to check if a number 044 is odd or even

Tags: logic-gates

simulation in a multisem  and steps truth table and k-map and circuit diagram of 044
design a logic c[image]ircuit odd/even driver to check if a number 044 is odd or even

Comment: Other than the title of this question, it's mostly gibberish.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Your solution could be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting your doubt, I'll be able to answer this. For detecting a number is odd or even we can design a circuit easily using a k-map. I am Assuming that the number 044(base 10) will be given as binary to the circuit. If IN0 is the lowest priority bit, you can simply attach a NOT gate to bit 0, which will be HIGH when bit 0 is LOW, indicating the binary number is EVEN. For the ODD number detector, directly connect the output to the bit 0, which will be HIGH when bit 0 is HIGH, indicating the ODD number. Although I am not sure if your doubt was this or not. If something else, write to me in the comment.